# Can't find the gh-pages option while I want to establish my project's GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-pages

Now , here is my all options of setting a github page of setting my project , but I can't find the gh-pages option... So, can someone tell the reason?  Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you did not create a branch labeled gh-pages

In Terminal on a mac you can create a branch or in GitHub for Desktop.

For Terminal,

navigate to the folder you ran

```
git init
```

and run

```
git status
```

That will tell you if git is installed in that folder.

Branches will be listed by running the command

```
git branch
```

Switch branches by running the command

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

```
git checkout master
```

Always run a git status to make sure your files are being tracked.

You can push the commits in Terminal, but I would use GitHub for Desktop app.

In Finder, you can see hidden (git) files by running command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

You will have to kill Finder for that to take effect, so then run

```
killall Finder
```

I have a brief article I wrote here: https://dougstate.com/how-to-show-hide-folders-in-os-x/